# d3.js issues. Appending div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have some application, that should build graphics according to values from database. I should use d3.js
I use [this guide](http://alignedleft.com/tutorials/d3/drawing-divs).
Code of [example](http://alignedleft.com/content/03-tutorials/01-d3/80-drawing-divs/2.html) works fine.
Here it is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>D3 Demo: 5 divs with data</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../d3/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">

            div.bar {
                display: inline-block;
                width: 20px;
                height: 75px;   /* Gets overriden by D3-assigned height below */
                background-color: teal;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var dataset = [ 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 ];

            d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
                .data(dataset)
                .enter()
                .append("div")
                .attr("class", "bar")
                .style("height", function(d) {
                    return d + "px";
                });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is part of my code, that doesn't work for some reason:

```
 d3.select("body").selectAll("p.bar")
 .data(prices)
 .enter()
 .append("p")
 .attr("class","bar")
 .style("height",function(d){
     return d+"px";
 });
```

Here is full index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<style>
    div.bar {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 20px;
        height: 75px;  
        background-color: teal;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<body>
<form action="./companyList" class="form-horizontal"  >
Начало периода:
<input type="text" name="beginDate" id="beginDate"></input>
Конец периода:
<input type="text" name="endDate" id="endDate"></input>
<input type="submit"></input>
<div id="listOfCompanies">
<h1>Список компаний</h1>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url: "./companyList",
        data: {"beginDate":$("#beginDate").text(),"endDate":$("#endDate").text()},  
        success: function(output){
        $("#listOfCompanies").html(output);
        $("#result").html("It works fine");
        },
        error:function(){
        alert("failure");
        $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
        }
    });

});
</script>
</div>
</form>
<div id="result">

</div>
<div id="invisible" >
</div>
<div id="invisible1" >
123
</div>
<script>
$(".form-horizontal").submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var request=$.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url: "./listOfPrices",
        data: {"beginDate":$("#beginDate").val(),"endDate":$("#endDate").val(),"company":$(".company:checked").val()},  
        success: function(result){
        $("#invisible").html(result);
        },
        error:function(){
        alert("failure");
        $("#result").html('There is error while submit');
        }
        });
    $( document ).ajaxComplete(function(){
        var tmp=$("#invisible").text().split("+");
        var dates=tmp[0].split("|");
        var prices=tmp[1].split("|");
        var monthAbbreviations = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
        var formattedDates=new Array();
        for (var i=0;i<dates.length;i++){
            var tmpDate=new Date(dates[i]);
            var day = tmpDate.getUTCDate();
            var mo = monthAbbreviations[tmpDate.getUTCMonth()];
            var yr = tmpDate.getUTCFullYear();
            var formattedDate = day + '-' + mo + '-' + yr;
            formattedDates.push(formattedDate);
        }
        console.log(prices);
        d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
            .data(prices)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("class","bar")
            .style("height",function(d){
                return prices+"px";
            })
            //.style("margin-right","2px");
    });
});
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

That just doesn't append any height to divs. Also, when I change it to selectAll("div"); there is no any divs added. Can anyone explain?

Comment: You probably want `.selectAll("p.bar")` and then `.style("height", function(d) { return d + "px; })`.

Comment: I did it as you say. Still doesn't works.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the semicolon, because you commented the last line. Also you should reference "d" instead of "prices" inside the 'height-style-function', as Lars Kotthoff already commented.  Then it also might be a problem to put a div inside a p-element. But i'm not sure about that. If the first two hints don't help, try to change the appended "div" to a "p"-element and don't forget to modify your css then.

```
 d3.select("body").selectAll("p")
        .data(prices)
        .enter()
        .append("div")
        .attr("class","bar")
        .style("height",function(d){
            return d+"px";
        });
```

Comment: Lol, the problem was, that I get a price in float. I used your solution, so I accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you really want but I build a simple case and I think it may be enough for this problem, please check [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/55DLc/) for detail.

the important code is you should use ENTER, UPDATE and EXIT together, just append isn't enough. the following is related code.

```
var price = [10,30,20,50];

var svg = d3.select("body").selectAll("div")
.data(price);

svg.enter()
.append("div")
.attr("class","bar")
.style("height",function(d){
    return d+"px";
});

svg.attr("class","bar")
.style("height",function(d){
    return d+"px";
});

svg.exit().remove();
```